# Flow on Case Is Not Accessing Account

Tags: visual-workflow

Riddle me this, riddle me that...

### Prelude

We have a Screen Flow on the Case object.  When a user clicks *Next* it (is supposed to) check whether there is a value in one custom field on the associated Account.

Using new Summer '20 setup, the entire Case record is passed into the Flow:

[image]

Inside the Flow, when I access the `caseRecord` variable, I can select from the myriad fields (standard and custom) and almost all of the objects (standard and custom) related to the Case:

[image]

However, conspicuously missing is `Account ID      >`.

There are some Account-related fields (including `AccountId`) on the Case that I can access, but that only gets me so far.  I need a field on (and later in the Flow, an object related to) the Account.

---

## Question

#### What could be causing this?

---

### What I've Checked & Tried

- Compared the *Field-Level Security* of this field:
  [image]
  to all the other `Lookup(<Object>)` fields on the Case object, and there *seems* to be nothing that is in or not in the `AccountId` field that is not also not in or in some or all of the other `Lookup` fields that are accessible in the `caseRecord` Flow variable.
- Checked what I've thought to check in *Permission Sets*, but I don't see anything obvious to me.
- Manually typing out `{!caseRecord.Account.Custom_Field__c}` and `...AccountId...`:

  > Results in an *Enter a valid value.* error
- Changed *How to Run the Flow* to try both System Context options.
- Verified that the following SOQL query returns a valid result: `SELECT Account.Custom_Field__c FROM Case WHERE Id = 'xyzzy'`

---

### Workarounds

1. I can access the Account fields and related objects within the Flow by the following route (where `Opportunity_ID__c` is a `Lookup(Opportunity)` we've added to the Case object):

   `{!caseRecord.Opportunity_ID__r.Account.Custom_Field__c}`

   However, not all Cases of the Record Type using this Flow will have Opportunities associated to them, so that will not work long-term.
2. Do a **Get Records** step using `{!caseRecords.AccountID}`.  (This is the current "let's go with it" workaround.)

---

### Postlude

I am hoping I am having a "Doh!" moment and it is something simple (though I will feel foolish after writing all of this....)

Comment: very weird but in my scratch org it seems to show up AccountId field fine.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava - For clarification (maybe got lost in my sea of information): I can access/see the `Case.AccountId` field just fine.  I just cannot directly access the Account as a relationship (so that I can use the Account fields or the Account's relationships) using the Case record variable.

Comment: Yes and I was able to access account and it’s parent account and other fields of account relationships.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I started a new Flow (the one above is quite complex) with only a Case record variable. Then I added a Decision Step. In this step, when I chose the variable in the picklist, the same thing occurred: I could not access the Account as a relationship. So since you can and I can't, it appears to be permission/visibility; but I cannot pinpoint it....